# UIGetScreenImage the app is not getting the approval due to this method

Tags: iphone, xcode

HI i am using zxing API into my application and it says that the application  cannot be posted to the App Store because it is using private or undocumented APIs:

Private Symbol References
UIGetScreenImage

can somebody help me out as soon as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZXing 1.6, which was released yesterday, has switched to the AV Foundation classes of iOS 4. It's the real-time scanning approach that's allowed by Apple.

**Update:**

ZXing 1.6 comes with three iPhone projects:

- **Barcodes** is the original iPhone app. It's still using the *UIGetScreenImage* API.
- **ZXingWidget** is a library that you can include into your own app. It uses the new AV Foundation classes.
- **ScanTest** is a sample app using *ZXingWidget*

So the way to go is to use the *ZXingWidget*.

Comment: i downloaded that new version but it still uses the UIGetScreenImage to get the image and this is what is rejectint the app ..is there any other solution .

Comment: Strange. I had a look at the latest development version a few days ago, and the code was there (even though I didn't run it). Just search for _AVCaptureSession_ in the source code. For real-time scanning (as opposed to taking a picture and then scanning it), the AV Foundation classes are the only solution.

Comment: I guess you tried the _Barcodes_ app. Try _ScanTest_ instead. See my update of the answer.

Comment: yes i integrated the Barcodes app and then i changed to scannerkit sdk which is really good and worked for me well .. again thanks for your inputs..

Answer (score 0):

ZXing is displaying the feed from the camera live on the screen, and using UIGetScreenImage to repeatedly capture the resulting image without the user having to do anything.  (This is a very nice user experience because the user doesn't have to press a button to take a picture of the barcode; the app just keeps taking pictures over and over until it gets one that works.)

This technique used to be perfectly fine, but [Apple has recently changed their policy and banned the use of UIGetScreenImage](http://www.tuaw.com/2010/07/21/devsugar-rip-uigetscreenimage/).  In light of Apple's change in policy, your best choice now is to make it so the user has to press a button to photograph the barcode manually.

Since ZXing is open-source, this should be a simple matter of changing a few lines of code to now use [[UIImagePickerController takePicture]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImagePickerController/takePicture).