# How to take a screenshot programmatically in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, uikit, screenshot

I have a `UIView` that uses both `UIKit` control and `OpenGL`. I'd like to get a screenshot of that view programatically.

If I use `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()`, the `OpenGL` content is blank;
If I use the `glReadPixels(...)` method, the UIKit content is blank;

I'm confused as how to take a complete screenshot.
Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

use following code to take screen shot

```
    -(UIImage *) screenshot
     {

          CGRect rect;
          rect=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
          UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);

          CGContextRef context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
          [self.view.layer renderInContext:context];

          UIImage *image=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
          UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

          return image;
     }
```

Comment: This code is just for take UIKit stuff...The question is more complex and well explained: he need to take also OpenGL stuff.

Answer (score 5):

Well, there are few ways of capturing the iPhone screen programmatically

1. Using UIKIT http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1703/_index.html
2. Using AVFoundation framework http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1702/_index.html
3. Using OpenGL ES
   http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1704/_index.html
4. Starting from iOS 7 you can also use [Why does my programmatically created screenshot look so bad on iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956611/programmatically-screenshot-works-bad-on-ios-7)
5. Using UIWindow

   ```
   CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenRect.size);
   CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
   [[UIColor blackColor] set];
   CGContextFillRect(ctx, screenRect);
   [self.window.layer renderInContext:ctx];
   UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   ```
6. Using UIView

   ```
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
   [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
   UIImage *viImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   ```

Out of these 6 options, I found the first option very convenient for copy-pasting and for applying level of compression as 1st method gives the image with true pixel data. I also like option 4, as the API comes with SDK.

Comment: Thanks for this, it seems that screens with sub-view controllers don't auto-add child view controller layers.  But using the window seems to work for a full-screen image.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
-(UIImage *) screenshot
{
CGImageRef UIGetScreenImage(void);
CGImageRef screen = UIGetScreenImage();
UIImage* screenImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:screen];
CGImageRelease(screen); // you need to call this.
return screenImage;
}
```

Comment: Can someone explain how it works? Also need to fix the orientation

Comment: definitely not the way to go [this is why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767860/uigetscreenimage-the-app-is-not-getting-the-approval-due-to-this-method)

Answer (score 2):

You get result Uiimage without lose quality of image

```
    - (UIImage *)captureView:(UIView *)view {
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
     [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
     UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
     return img;
     }
```

Comment: it doesn't take effects in an OpenGL page

Answer (score 1):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSData *data = [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) retain];
UImage *screenShot = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Comment: it only take effects in UIKit condition, for OpenGL page, only get blank image

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can take a simple screenshot programmatically of a `UIImage`. If you want it for any other object substitute the `UIImage` with it.

In the `.h` file add  `NSData *Data;` then in your `.m` file add this to your code

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *attachimage = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:Data];
UIImage *viImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
attachimage = viImage;
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: it only take effects in UIKit condition, for OpenGL page, only get blank image

Answer (score 0):

You know where the OpenGL content is located in your view. So it should be easy to copy the result of `glReadPixels` into the snapshot of the UIKit.

Comment: I'm developing a screenshot control, I don't know whether the view is implemented by UIKit or OpenGL, or mixed. If I can get the info that the view is implemented by what, the problem will be solved.

Comment: @coodi8 I think this could be a problem. Won't be easy because OpenGL renders directly on the graphic chip. UI-Graphics are not rendered on the graphics chip. ( AFAIK )

Answer (score 0):

maybe.. can you use something from here

[- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413460/cocos2d-2-0-screenshots-on-ios-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413460/cocos2d-2-0-screenshots-on-ios-6)

and here...

[Why is glReadPixels() failing in this code in iOS 6.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528365/why-is-glreadpixels-failing-in-this-code-in-ios-6-0)