# UIGraphics crashes on iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7

I have an app which has been extensively tested with iOS 6 and works well, while on iOS 7 it crashes almost always (but not 100% times) with an `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error in the main, without much to trace. I am completely clueless of its whereabouts. I believe something in my code is not compatible with the core iOS methods.

The best I could identify is, upon commenting the following part of the code everything runs well.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(coverView.bounds.size);
[coverView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *coverImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(coverImage, 0.8f) writeToFile:coverFilePath atomically:YES];

//Create thumbnail of cover image
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(116.0f, 152.0f);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
[coverImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, size.width, size.height)];
coverImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(coverImage, 0.8f) writeToFile:coverThumbnailFilePath atomically:YES];
```

Can anyone suggest me where I should go debugging next? Kindly note that the same App works fantastic in iOS 6 and this bug is very much iOS 7 specific.

**EDIT**: The zombie stack trace is attached: I could not make use of it much so far, but might be useful for expert eyes :)

[image]

Thanks in advance,

Nikhil

Comment: Did you turn on exception breakpoints?  I think not because you are talking about a crash in main.  Turn them on (there are many guides here and on google) and then you will find a more specific line.

Comment: Go to `Breakpoint Navigator`, tap plus sign and `Add Exception breakpoint` and select `Exception on Throw`. Then build and run and paste here more specific log. Then we will be able to help you.

Comment: I have them turned on, but they do not catch anything :(. The crash seems in memory. I suspect I am referring something I (read ARC) released before somewhere.

Comment: Please show us `coverThumbnailFilePath` also. When breakpoint is set `On Throw` you should have selected line when app crashes. You doing something wrong. Please paste log when app crashes. This breakpoint great catch `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crashes.

Comment: @TomaszSzulc, I have `All Exceptions` turned on. Still no luck. I will post the coverThumbnailFilePath shortly, but surprisingly the crash occurs even when everything is commented but the first two lines, i.e. `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(coverView.bounds.size);
[coverView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];` ... I think something's wrong with either UIGraphics or my use of it.

Comment: Check before rendering if `.layer` isn't `nil`. And check if `coverView.bounds.size` isn't equals `(0,0)`.

Comment: checked no help. It crashes even when coverView has good size and a layer :(.... also, all of this works well with iOS 6. The crash is iOS 7 specific.

Comment: is your code part of an custom `UIView` within a view controller? I had similar issues with transfering from iOS 6 to 7 when my custom `UIView` was initiated with starting the view controller. in that early stage the UIView was expecting data from the view controller which wasn't available and crashed.

Comment: Actually my proposal would be to make sure that all necessary data are available to the view when it gets initiated. prevent code getting executed to early necessary for the `UIView`.

Comment: @JFS, I always do lazy instantiation whenever possible. Though I will double check. Thanks :)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to grab a screenshot. Things have changed in iOS7 - I'm too lazy to write an answer, but this SO link should help http://stackoverflow.com/q/18956611/41116

Comment: @Abizern Thanks for the reference. I tried it with no luck.
However, one interesting thing is if I change the `afterScreenUpdate:` from `YES` to `NO` the problem is gone. Of course I want the screen shot to be taken after I updated the screen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, Finally I got it working. That was a nice learning experience overall :).

Actually the very nature of "EXE_BAD_ACCESS" did hint towards bad memory management, i.e. I was requesting access to something non-existent. Unfortunately, (or quite logically, which I missed earlier) leaks would not find it. But they were caught when I profiled my app for `zombies`.

The problem occurred due to the method

```
   [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];   // iOS 7
```

or equivalently in iOS 6

```
   [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

The sequence of my app progress was something like this:

```
   render view -> update a few things -> request a screenshot be taken on update
   -> update the view -> return to previous view (releasing this one)
```

Now, because I demanded the screen shots be taken upon update, these methods waited till the view update occurs. However, immediately after the update I was releasing the superview. And hence these methods (after waiting for the update) called `this` view after it was released.

Now, I don't know if this is Apple's iOS bug or my poor understanding of it. But now, I don't release the superview immediately upon view update and everything works fine :).

Thanks guys for your help. Let me know if I am doing something odd here and this behavior can be prevented in a more efficient way.

best,
Nikhil

Answer (score 1):

If your UIView's height is nearly zero(such as 0.1), `drawViewHierarchyInRect: afterScreenUpdates:` will crash. So check the size before you call it.

PS: This only happens on iOS 7

Answer (score 0):

Got few similar problems with iOS7, due to autolayout issues (my issues). Be sure that the size exist and is valid, for example a size with 0,0, can't create a valid graphics context.
I also add a method that you can us as a category on UIView to get screenshot of a particular view. If on iOS6 or lower it uses the well know `-renderInContext:`, if on iOS7 it uses the new `-drawViewHierarchyInRect::` really faster than the first, se if you get crashes also using that.

```
- (UIImage *) imageByRenderingViewOpaque:(BOOL) yesOrNO {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, yesOrNO, 0);

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:)]) {
        [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    }
    else {
        [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    }
    UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return resultingImage;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrea. This does not solve my issue and the app still crash :(

Comment: Did you check the state of the UIView before sending the message?

Comment: yes... I did. It's perfectly fine with its size and dimensions