# make screenshot of the whole screen in ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, screenshot, theos

I'm trying to take screenshot of the whole screen from a command line tool compiled with [THEOS](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos).
I've tried all the Private APIs UICreateScreenImage, UIGetScreenImage and _UICreateScreenUIImage, all return a black or empty image (but the size of the picture is correct)

This is my code that use the "_UICreateScreenUIImage" API:

```
    extern "C" UIImage* _UICreateScreenUIImage();

    int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp) {

        UIImage* screenImage = _UICreateScreenUIImage();

        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(screenImage) writeToFile:@"/var/mobile/screenshot.png" atomically:YES];

        [screenImage release];
        return 0;
    }
```

I've linked the frameworks: Foundation UIKit QuartzCore CoreGraphics  and GraphicsServices as private framework.
I can't use the Apple way described here [Why does my programmatically created screenshot look so bad on iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956611/programmatically-screenshot-works-bad-on-ios-7)  because is a command line tool.
Any suggestions?

Comment: don't you need to specify the size of screen? width, height?

Comment: Hi, no the API do all the job, indeed the size of the (black) picture is correct.

Answer (score 2):

you can try my code. It worked for me.

**Option 1:**

```
- (void)takeScreenshotAndSaveToPhotosAlbum {
    extern UIImage *_UICreateScreenUIImage();
    UIImage *screenshot = _UICreateScreenUIImage();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
typedef struct __IOSurface *IOSurfaceRef;
UIKIT_EXTERN CGImageRef UICreateCGImageFromIOSurface(IOSurfaceRef);

- (void)takeScreenshotAndSaveToPhotosAlbum {
    IOSurfaceRef ioSurfaceRef = (__bridge IOSurfaceRef)([UIWindow performSelector:@selector(createScreenIOSurface)]);
    CGImageRef cgImageRef = UICreateCGImageFromIOSurface(ioSurfaceRef);
    UIImage *uiImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImageRef];
    CFRelease(ioSurfaceRef);
    CGImageRelease(cgImageRef);
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(uiImage, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

Comment: The first option badly leaks memory. The second one only creates black images.

Comment: Option 1 should be declared as `OBJC_EXTERN UIImage *_UICreateScreenUIImage(void) NS_RETURNS_RETAINED;` if you develop under ARC. In MRC, you should release it.